# Modal form is not functioning

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post

So I have this code in the modal in Bootstrap, which is meant to run a PHP script named 'changepassword.php'. The PHP script exists but when I press the 'Save button' button, it doesn't run the script? Any ideas?

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Username <span class="label label-default">Change password</span></h4>
</div>
<form id="passwordchange" name="cp" method="post" action="scripts/changepassword.php">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="password" name="vpass" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        <input type="password" name="vnpass" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        <input type="password" name="vcnpass" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="passwordchange-b" name="sumbit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save password</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The submit button needs the duplicated type attribute removing (type="button").